# Python random numbers with lots of Raw_Inputs, Debugging

Tags: debugging, random, count, int, raw-input

```
import random
count=0
other=0
inp=raw_input('Enter number of #s: ')
bottom=raw_input('Enter min: ')
upper=raw_input('Enter max: ')
middle=raw_input('Provide middle number')
for x in range(int(inp)):
    a=random.randint(((int(bottom)(int(upper)))))
    #print a
    if (a>middle):
        count=count+1
    elif (a<middle):
        other=other+1

print count, "numbers over 1500"
print other, "numbers under 1500"
```

Okay, so I am trying to make so that a "user" can provide all variables needed to run the code. Previously I made a stupid spelling error. Having fixed that I am now receiving a (TypeError: 'int' object is not callable) error attributed to line 9, the one with all the ()'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is quite simple : you made a typo in raw_input (on the line with middle), using m instead of n.

Also, randint should take 2 arguments (assuming this is python), so you are missing a comma

Comment: firstly, wow... sorry...
secondly, fixed that stupid error, now i get a (TypeError: 'int' object is not callable) error. which is odd, to me at least

Comment: What does your line 9 looks like now?

Comment: same, i've been playing around with the order and such to no change

Comment: figured out line 9:
a=random.randint(int(bottom),int(upper))

Comment: try using `a=random.randint(int(bottom), int(upper))` instead. I removed lots of un-needed () and a comma to separate the randint's arguments

Comment: okay, new problem, same code.
ive been running the code a few times with 10 #'s with a range of 1-10 and no matter how many times I do, it always comes out as "numbers under 1500" is always all the numbers even when its not, by printing a

Comment: Nevermind, found it : you are not casting middle as an int. replace if (a > middle) by if (a > int(middle) ), and something similar for the elif

Comment: You are correct! thanks for all your trouble shooting that did it!
the new proper functioning code is:

Comment: import random
    count=0
    other=0
    inp=raw_input('Enter number of #s: ')
    bottom=raw_input('Enter min: ')
    upper=raw_input('Enter max: ')
    middle=raw_input('Provide middle number: ')
    for x in range(int(inp)):
        a=random.randint(int(bottom),int(upper))
        print a
        if (a > int(middle)):
            count=count+1
        elif (a < int(middle)):
            other=other+1

    print count, "numbers over middle"
    print other, "numbers under middle"